# Expected Value of consecutive results of coin flipping

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, expected-value

I'd very much appreciate your help in finding a solution to the following problem.
We take a fair coin, and flip it $n$ times. What would be the expected value of the longest
consecutive run of a certain result?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome, please see [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please add what you've tried to the body of the question. Thanks and good luck.

Comment: Before asking, please search if the question has not been answered before.